# How to show the data from foreign key in case of different column name in CDetailView Yii

Tags: php, yii, cdetailview

How to show the data from foreign key **in case of different column name** in **CDetailView** Yii

Table1

```
x1      x2
1       sample text 1
2       sample text 2
3       sample text 3
```

Table2

```
y1      y2          y3 (foreign key x1)
1       text 1      1
2       text 2      1
3       text 3      2
```

**I want to show the following result**

```
y1      y2          y3
1       text 1      sample text 1
2       text 2      sample text 1
3       text 3      sample text 2
```

This is relation Code in Model Class

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
         'Table2' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Table1', array('x1'=>'y3'))
    );
}
```

This is my CDetailView Code

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
         array(
             'name'=>'Table2.y3',
             'value'=>$model->Table2->x2,
         ),
         'y1',
         'y2'
    ),
)); ?>
```

**I am getting the following Error**

```
Property "Table2.x1" is not defined.
```

Comment: you can directly use y3 instead of `array('x1'=>'y3')` in your table2 `relation`

Comment: But @kumar_v i want to show the foreign value against the y3 instead of some y3 value

Comment: did you try in code? I think you have this relation in table1 model. right? try and tell me the result.

Comment: Yes i have tried this `Table2.y3` then it shows `y3` id instead of value. Let me tell you one thing more, I don't have define any physical relation in MySQL Database. @Kumar_v Please help me to solve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: ok sure. did you try below solution?

Comment: Yes. But its not working. I get the Error `Trying to get property of non-object` and `Property "Table2.x1" is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

First problem: the relations are not defined properly (as far as I can understand from the info provided)

Relations in model of `Table1`

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
         'Table2' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Table2', 'y3')
    );
}
```

As one object of table1's model will have many table2's objects

Relations in model of `Table1`

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
         'Table1' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Table1', 'y3')
    );
}
```

As one object of table2's model belongs to some table's object..

Now after defining the relations properly you can use `'value'=>$data->Table2->x2,` to print value from the relation..

Comment: I have tried these both solutions but I get following errors. 
From solution 1 `Trying to get property of non-object` and from solution 2 `Property "Table2.x1" is not defined`

Comment: This is not solution1 or solution2 its a complete solution..read carefully,,